# Flight delay compensation due to weather (EU)

Tags: air-travel, uk, eu

My friend is due to fly to Jersey today from Gatwick by Easyjet this morning and return to London from Jersey in the evening

Both flights are cancelled.

My question is which leg can she claim flight delay compensation for? I am of the opinion that he can definitely claim for the evening flight. The reason is as follows:

- The return flight is 20:25 in the evening - BA have a scheduled flight at 20:10 from Jersey to Gatwick so the weather condition is definitely okay for this. Hence this is due to Easyjet not having a plane ready, and not force majeure
- The outward flight is dubious. There were lots of flights flying out of Gatwick in the morning but unfortunately all the flights destined for Jersey were cancelled.

Knowing Easyjet, there is a real possibility that they would refuse to pay out. Just wondering if there is a chance expectation to get a pay out for the evening flight if my friend takes Easyjet to court.

Comment: It can still be outside the airline's control when some flights go and others are cancelled: In bad weather, fewer runway slots are available.

Comment: Remember too that outbound flights from airports with snow and ice need de-icing, which really reduces airport capacity as it takes several minutes to de-ice each plane.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can attempt to claim compensation under [EU261](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?qid=1476179175834&uri=CELEX:32004R0261) for the flight from Jersey to the UK, but if EasyJet claims the cancellation is due to ***either*** meteorological ***or*** air traffic control management (such as reduced slot available, as suggested by @user16259) then you face a significant uphill battle, as EasyJet are not the only airline cancelling flights into Gatwick at the moment.

I wouldn't rate the chances of a court case being successful.

Comment: okay, i won't pursue this then. i will hand the case to a no win-no fee case handler. any compensation won is free upside. :) i always hated claiming flight delay compensation.

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely submit a claim for compensation but would not necessarily take the airline to court if they refuse. The Civil Aviation Authority perhaps? They may save your friend a good amount of court expenses.

As others have said, [extraordinary circumstances (e.g. bad weather, control tower instructions)](https://skyrefund.com/en/blog/extraordinary-circumstances-right-to-compensation) may have been the reason for the delay. If so, then your friend would not be entitled to compensation. The CAA would probably be the best institution to determine this.